# all permutation/combination to fill slots with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my problem :

I have a 5 slots space that i must fill with all the possibility (even repetitions) with a given a dataframe serie :

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
len_combination = 5
```

i would like to get :

```
AAAAA
```

as

```
A
CC
B
BA
AB
AAAAB
AABAA
DAACB
```

i've tried with itertools but with combination i didn't manage to repeat the letters and with product i didn't manage to  produce only one letter.

Regards

Comment: Please clarify your question. I especially can't understand what that output is.

Comment: Is the order important? (Is BA the same as AB)

Comment: No AB is not the same as BA thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with the `itertools.product` idea:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

combs = pd.DataFrame(list(product(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], repeat=5)))

In [95]: q.combs.head()
Out[95]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  A  A  A  A  A
1  A  A  A  A  B
2  A  A  A  A  C
3  A  A  A  A  D
4  A  A  A  B  A
```

Edit: If you want to generate permutations of subsets with fewer than 5 elements, you can simply chain the above approach:

```
from itertools import chain
combs_generator = chain(*(product('ABCD', repeat=k) for k in range(1,6)))
combs = pd.DataFrame(list(combs_generator))

       0     1     2     3 

4
0     A  None  None  None  None
1     B  None  None  None  None
2     C  None  None  None  None
3     D  None  None  None  None
4     A     A  None  None  None
5     A     B  None  None  None
6     A     C  None  None  None
7     A     D  None  None  None
8     B     A  None  None  None
9     B     B  None  None  None
10    B     C  None  None  None
11    B     D  None  None  None
12    C     A  None  None  None
13    C     B  None  None  None
14    C     C  None  None  None
15    C     D  None  None  None
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants repeats 1, 2, ..., 5; not just 5.